# update hash by method to save in db Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to update a hash that is being made when a csv is uploaded by a user, so that it saves the added key/value pair to the db.

How can I update the hash being made in the `create_by_location` method with the method `check_enable_recordings`

user model

```
before_save :check_enable_recordings

  def check_enable_recordings
    x = tenant.enable_recording_extensions
    Rails.logger.debug("check if true #{x}" )
    if x
      user = User.new(
        recorded:  "1"
      )
      end

  end


def self.create_by_location(location,hash)

    user = User.new(
      first_name:             hash[:firstname],
      last_name:              hash[:lastname],
      email:                  hash[:email],
    )
end
```

Comment: There appears to be no question...

Comment: @jvillian I will update my question to be more specific, but my question is how am I able to update the `user` hash with the `check_enable_recrodings` method so that it saves into the db

Comment: You mean user model? Secondly, your `check` method is defined where? If it's in `User` then you shouldn't be creating a new user, you should be doing `self.recorded = "1"`.

Comment: @tadman it is all in the `User model`, I didn't even realize that it was that simple of a fix. Thank You! if you put it as the answer below I will mark it correct

Comment: I'm supposing what you want to do is set a property on the user *that is being saved* and not create a completely new user with just one property set, yeah.

Comment: When you say you are trying to 'update the hash being made in the `create_by_location` method', do you mean the `user` being made? Because, there is no hash being made in the `create_by_location` method...

Comment: @jvillian yes I meant user being made, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you're looking for something like:

```
before_save :check_enable_recordings

def check_enable_recordings
  self.recorded = 1 if tenant.enable_recording_extensions
end

def self.create_by_location(location,hash)
  user = User.new(
    first_name:   hash[:firstname],
    last_name:    hash[:lastname],
    email:        hash[:email],
  )
end
```

BTW, you don't seem to use the `location` argument anywhere. Maybe you're not showing us all the code.

Also, if you have control over the construction of the `hash` argument, you should probably change `firstname` to `first_name` and `lastname` to `last_name` so you can just do:

```
def self.create_by_location(location,hash)
  user = User.new(hash)
end
```

Comment: This needs to be `self.recorded = 1` otherwise you're declaring a variable called `recorded` that gets thrown away.

Comment: @tadman Updated and thank you! My lack of understanding is showing through. I was thinking that `recorded=` would be a setter method generated by ActiveRecord based on the database table structure and, therefore, `recorded = 1` would set the model attribute rather than generating a temporary variable. I guess that's all wrong???

Comment: While you can do things like `if recorded` and it will call the method, `=` never does. You must be explicit, doing `self.recorded = 1`.